# how to rotate the normal map so that it always looks at one of the axes on the controller object?

Tags: shaders, normals

Like this. It should work like this in the end.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can align Euler to Vector in geonodes:

[image]

And then use it in the shader to rotate normals:

[image]

[image]

It may look confusing with Suzanne, so here's the same setup with a sphere:

[image]